# Does page verification mode affect DBCC CHECKDB behavior?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, dbcc-checkdb

Does DB page verification mode (torn page vs checksum) affect DBCC CHECKDB behavior?  Have some large (TBs) older db's still with TORN page detection mode and curious if check db works any better / worse / slower / faster based upon page verification mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended to set a database to use Page Verify CHECKSUM.The Checksum is safer and its performance overhead is still small enough.
As discussed in this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/checksum-page-verification-in-sql-server/).

> When changing a database to use CHECKSUM it is important to know that
> the option isn’t used for pages that have already been written to disk
> and as such it will only be applied to new pages are written or when
> existing pages are modified and re-written to the IO subsystem.
>
> A common misconception regarding the CHECKSUM option is that it
> replaces the need for consistency checking databases. This is a very
> incorrect assumption; as we’ve seen the CHECKSUM error is only
> reported on the read operation of an inconsistent page, if the page
> isn’t read the error isn’t reported. However the biggest reason is
> that the DBCC CHECKDB routine performs a lot more thorough checking at
> the database level and includes checks that a CHECKSUM simply doesn’t
> cover, therefore the best practice is to combine CHECKSUM page
> verification and regular consistency checks.

Comment: This [page](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5226/undetected-sql-server-data-corruption-with-database-page-verify-option-set-to-none/) indicates that page verification mode can influence dbcc checkdb success / failure.

Answer (score 1):

Torn Page Detection is the more lightweight, but Checksum is safer, and its overhead is still small enough that it's the better option.
CHECKSUM should have the most significant impact as it requires calculating checksums for all IO operations but it shouldn't be an issue.

Please refer to [this thread](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/torn_page_detection-vs-checksum) which may help.

Regards,

Amelia